# Sorry... it is still very hard for me to understand this sentence's meaning

Tags: meaning

What does this sentence mean?

> This is done by creating and sustaining demand for Water, Sanitation
>   and Hygiene services and by providing an enabling environment to
>   assure the supply side and institutional set up.

I guess the meaning of

> This is done by creating and sustaining demand for Water, Sanitation
>   and Hygiene services

is

> This is done by making and keeping necessaries of Water, Sanitation
>   and Hygiene services.

However, I can not understand the meaning of

> by providing an enabling environment to assure the supply side and institutional set up

I would really appreciate it if you could help me as I have to translate this sentence to my language.

Comment: Cathay, you should really edit [your previous question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/447919/please-teach-me-this-sentences-meaning). Still, it's here now. What have you done to find the meaning of *providing; enabling environment; assure; supply side; institutional; set-up*? Please edit in your actual research. The point is, once you have done that, we can help you see if you are right, or where you are going wrong, and that will help in the future.

Comment: Cathay, please look up the type of question that is on-topic, at the help center. This, like most questions on interpretation, is far too broadly scoped. ELU is not a free interpretation service.

Comment: The meaning you guess at (“This is done by making and keeping necessaries of Water, Sanitation and Hygiene services”) does not actually make any sense in English.

Answer (score 1):

It is management speak or jargon. From a government standpoint, "providing an enabling environment" probably means making it easier to for companies to get official permission/authorization to do the things proposed. As our colleague notes above, the question is "far too broadly scoped" to give a more precise answer.